# Running debug session for lwpd.xsp.core source

Tags: java, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Assuming I have a decompiled source of lwpd.xsp.core library, is there any way to run it through Domino Designer Java debug session? I want to fully understand what happens behind the scenes, but IBM actually lacks any good documentation except apidoc that doesn't help too much. I think running the full request/response cycle from debugger would be the fastest and most effective way to clear things up, than browsing the code through IDE. On the other hand, I can put sout pritln-s where I need or insert some custom logging statements, but debugger is still preferred.

I guess maybe I have to remove lwpd.xsp.core.jar from Plug-in Dependencies of my XPages application and attach it as an external library instead, but I don't have a clue how to do it. If it is possible at all, I'll make a research on the topic.

Comment: Have you added the decompiled java sources during a debug session?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach IDE tells me that the current class path entry belongs to container 'Plug-in Dependencies' which does not allow user modifications to source attachments on its enties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decompile the code during runtime with the [JD GUI Eclipse Plugin](http://jd.benow.ca/). Just download the update site and import it into DDE.
No Source code needed.

And please donate for the project (I am not the author of JD GUI or have any benefits from a donation).

By the way: the most interesting parts of the XPages engine are stored in the files

- lwpd.xsp.core.jar
- lwpd.xsp.extsn.jar
- lwpd.xsp.domino.jar
- lwpd.xsp.designer

Comment: Yes, I've decompiled them all, first with standalone JD GUI, but it produced bytecode instead of java code inside some methods, and too much code had to be fixed to make it buildable, maybe there're some options that I've missed. Then I've tried the decompiler plugin that is shipped with IntelliJ IDEA. The plugin has a console wrapper so it can be used standalone. The output was much cleaner and I was able to rebuild all libs except xsp.domino, because I could never find a couple of classes to resolve its imports. I'll try the plugin and post back and donate on success

Comment: The results of the decompiling when using the standalone version are different then the eclipse plugin. E.g. the decompiling of the theme processing are not working in the standalone version, but the results are fine when doing this in DDE.